# Basler gentl camera not detecting in Matlab 2020a

Tags: drivers, matlab, camera

I am trying to use Basler acA1300-200uc in Ubuntu 20.04 through matlab and I have installed all the required add-ons for "gentl" adapter. Official pylonViewer software by basler detects the camera and it works perfectly. It works fine on windows and matlab 2020a

Output of imaqhwinfo

```
  ans = 

  struct with fields:

    InstalledAdaptors: {'gentl'  'gige'}
        MATLABVersion: '9.7 (R2019b)'
          ToolboxName: 'Image Acquisition Toolbox'
       ToolboxVersion: '6.1 (R2019b)'
```

Output of imaqtool

```
No devices were detected for the 'gentl' adaptor. For troubleshooting device detection issues, click here.
No devices were detected for the 'gige' adaptor. For troubleshooting device detection issues, click here.
No devices were detected for the 'gentl' adaptor. For troubleshooting device detection issues, click here.
No devices were detected for the 'gige' adaptor. For troubleshooting device detection issues, click here.
```